# slimScroll bar in ExtJS 4

Tags: jquery, extjs4

I need to customize my scroll bar. How to do that?
I've a simple gird panel. I want a slimScroll bar..... If it is only possible through JQuery,
 how to call jquery for slimScroll bar?

This is what I got so far

```
Ext.define('TestApplication.view.display.DisplayOne' ,{
    extend     : 'Ext.grid.Panel',
    alias      : 'widget.displayOne',
    height     : 280,
    width      : 742,
    padding    : 4,
    viewConfig : {
        stripeRows : true,
        forceFit   : true,
        emptyText  : 'No Records to display',
        getRowClass: function(record, index) {
            if (record.get('empNo') == '000') {
                return 'display-false';
            } 
        }
    },
    initComponent: function () {
        this.store   = 'RegistrationStore';
        this.columns = [
            {
                xtype    : 'rownumberer',
                width    : 40,
                sortable : false
            },
            {
                text     : 'Employee ID',
                sortable : false,
                dataIndex: 'empNo',
                sortable : false
            },
            {
                text     : 'Employee Name',
                sortable : false,
                dataIndex: 'fname',
                sortable : false,
                flex     : 1
            },
            {
                text     : 'Gender',
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'gender',
                sortable : false
            },       
            {
                text     : 'Branch',
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'branch',
                sortable : false
            },
            {
                text     : 'Religion',
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'religion',
                sortable : false
            },
            {
                text     : 'Marital',
                sortable : true,
                dataIndex: 'marital',
                sortable : false
            }
        ];

        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: i have a poor idea about the functionality of stackoverflow. how to do that...... Pls help as i'm new to this world.

Comment: It is possible by using webkit css commands but I never seeing any solution that worked in IE. So if you don't need a cross-browser support, you might use this approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the scroll bar by updating the sass file and rebuilding the css using compass.